# Цикл делает зависание браузера

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, в чем здесь может быть ошибка в цикле, что происходит зависание браузера

```
function getDateMonth(cost, percent, commission, extraCost){
  let endPay = (cost + extraCost) - 5000;

  let youPaid = 5000;
  let mounth = 1;

  for(mounth; 0 <= endPay; mounth++){
      if(((endPay * (percent * 0.01)) + commission) <= 5000){
        endPay = endPay - ((endPay * (percent * 0.01)) + commission);

      } 
      else {
        endPay = endPay - 5000;
      }
    youPaid = youPaid + endPay;
  }

  return `Ты за ${mounth} месяцев заплатишь ${youPaid - cost} издержек по кредиту`;
}

// console.log(getDateMonth(34499, 4, 500, 0));
// console.log(getDateMonth(34499, 3, 1000, 0));
// console.log(getDateMonth(34499, 2, 0, 6666));
```

Comment: Зависает на последнем тесте console.log(getDateMonth(34499, 2, 0, 6666)), остальные работают как положено. Попробую разобраться.

Comment: Проблема что в последнем тесте, комиссия 0. И никогда не выполняется условие 0 <= endPay.

Comment: Да действительно. Спасибо